# Eager Loading with Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, eager-loading

I am trying to use Laravel's Eager loading to solve the N+1 query problem in my store.

-A Product hasMany Variations, each variation has a price

-A store page lists all products along with their prices. Active members see discounted pricing hence the price() and regularPrice().

-I believe the min() and max() in scopeRegularPrice() are not being eager loaded properly.

**Is there a best practice for using aggregate functions for eager loading?**

Product Model
[image]

Controller
[image]

Blade Output
[image]
Query Results (via Blackfire Debugging Tool)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your local scope ought to be returning something. So add

```
public function scopeRegularPrice() {
    ...
    return 'something'
}
```

If you are already returning something, then sorry. I couldn't see any return statement in your code.

Comment: I uploaded the full function with return value. I had cut it off earlier to avoid any confusion. (I think the problem arises because I am calling min() and max() within scopeRegularPrice())

Comment: What is `scopeRegularPrice()` returning? an array? also when you compare, try to do `if ( $product->price != $product->regularPrice() )`. No parenthesis on price. Unless `price` is a function and not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The scope should return Querybuilder, any way;

you maybe its better to make it  regular price as attribute on product model;

make the the variations relation ordered by price.
and add this method to product class.

```
 public function getRegularPriceAttribute() {

       $variations = $this->variations;
       // Get the live variations by where on collection , not DB query.
       $liveVaries = $variations->where('live', true)->all();
      // the first is the cheapest because you the variations relation should be orderBy('price')
       if (! empty($liveVaries)) return [first($liveVaries)->price, last($liveVaries)->price];

       return [first($variations)->price, last($variations)->price];}
```